# IF-statement in controller not working, using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't really understand why this IF statement doesnt work?

```
class TimetablesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if (params[:search_term]).blank?
      flash[:error] = "the search field can't be empty"
      render 'index'
    else
      @results = Timetable.find_train_and_next_routes(params[:search_term])
    end
    #require 'pry'; binding.pry
  end

  def search
    render 'index'
  end
end
```

The error that I'm getting is this one:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
    28:               %button.btn(type="submit") Search
    29: %br
    30: %section.well.well-lg.well-center
    31: - @results.each do |train|
    32:   %ul.items-shell
    33:     %li
    34:     = train.train_id
```

Obviously @results is empty and if it's empty it shouln't call the method:**find_train_and_next_routes**
But the IF-check at the controller-level is not workking properly , wondering why?

**My code is** [here](https://github.com/yonipacheko/train_check/blob/master/app/controllers/timetables_controller.rb)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It does work. You have an error because your `@results` is `nil`, and in your `index.html.haml` (probably) you try to call `@results.each`. To fix it, you can check if there are any `@results` before rendering them in index:

```
- if @results.present?
```

Comment: Exactly, so OP just needs to check if it's empty before rendering the results

Comment: @Marek well it works but the code doesnt do what I want :) if the field is empty i shouln't call the method it should render over again the page... right?

Comment: @YoniGeek I don't understand what's your problem.

Comment: if the field is empty it should render once again the page and shouldn't  call the method @results = Timetable.find_train_and_next_routes(params[:search_term])

Comment: @YoniGeek so it does.

Comment: @YoniGeek what are your params while you're doing this request?

Comment: the param is empty, my interest is to catch up this scenario at the controller-level and do something there that doesnt break up the view

Comment: Paste relevant part of log (showing params) in your question.

Comment: @YoniGeek just like I wrote in my answer.

Comment: @MarekLipka let me think about it, I'll back get to u. ANy email I can write u back maybe? thanks for the interest and time!

Comment: @YoniGeek write here. Be sure I'm gonna reply.

Answer (score 0):

in this case @result is not empty, it is null. At the beginning of your controller put @result = [], this will initialize @result to be an empty array.

I don't think you should do this kind of checks in the view, controller is there to provide a result and to make sure required results are passed properly to the view.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, the `params[:search_term]` param isn't empty, 
but the result with that search term is

```
Timetable.find_train_and_next_routes(params[:search_term])
```

is empty, like searching for something that doesn't exist, you can simply fix it by adding a fallback option so the `each` doesn't break, and it won't need a condition in the view

```
@results = Timetable.find_train_and_next_routes(params[:search_term]) || []
```

Comment: hi there! let me ask u something...shall I write     if (params[:search_term]).empty? instead? the point is to catch up the problem and if it's empty I wont call the method from the model

Comment: the issue is that even if it's not empty the `find` returns nil

Comment: so I should check for nil instead?

Comment: i think the first condition is fine, because `''.blank? = true` and `nil.blank? = true`, so i think the if condition doesn't need any changes, just handle an empty result from the `find` and see if it still doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

I feel you made a mistake. Your @results return nil because it may not meet your condition.

```
where("departure_time >= ? AND start_location == ?" , "#{arrival_time}", "#{final_location}" )
```

this statement will return as empty array if it don't meet the condition. when you call methods **first** for empty array, then it will return as nil. That's why you got nil for @results.

Comment: Yes I feel that too. This the code in his Timetable.find_train_and_next_routes function. He should use only =

Comment: @I guess so too :) but right now Im just asking about the controller-level..but thanks for yr interest

Comment: @SokmesaKhiev in sql operator equal looks like `=` not `==`

Comment: I think it may be a root of problem too.

Comment: @Зелёный I knew but the mistake above was in the model that I copied to tell him what the error. And you found another error related sql syntax of sql.